# Regular Expression: find the lines contain certain word but not with other words

Tags: regex

I would like to find the lines contain certain word but not with other words
like.

- case 1: expect......... non-GAAP diluted EPS from continuing operations
- case 2: Projected........diluted EPS from continuing operations
- case 3: Projected........ adjusted diluted EPS from continuing operations

Here is my regex

```
(expect|project)(.*)(diluted\sEPS\sfrom\scontinuing\soperations)
```

but it's matching all three.

I want results from only case2, not from other two case.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you want to match `(expect|Projected)` followed by one or more dots and then the sentence `diluted EPS from continuing operations`.

If you want to match a literal dot you have to escape it `\`. In your regex `(.*)` will match any character zero or more times so that would match after `(expect|project)` until it encounters the word `diluted` and will match  `non-GAAP` and `adjusted`.

If you want to match a white space between a word you could match a literal whitespace instead of `\s`.

Try it like this:

[`(?:expect|Projected)\.+diluted EPS from continuing operations`](https://regex101.com/r/m1Tv56/1)

**That will match**

- `(?:expect|Projected)` Non capturing group which matches one of the 2 values
- `\.+` Match one or more dots
- `diluted EPS from continuing operations` Match you sentence